# Unlabelled simple graphs with $k$ edges

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

> Let $G(n,k)$ denote the set of unlabeled simple graphs (i.e. without loops). Prove that for $k<\frac{1}{2}\binom{n}{2}$ we have $|G(n,k)|\leq |G(n,k+1)|$.

A naive constructive argument on $k$ by taking a graph on $G(n,k)$ and adding an edge to lift it to $G(n,k+1)$ doesn't work since two different graphs in $G(n,k)$ can become isomorphic when you add an edge. Is there a simple proof to this without resorting to counting polynomials and exact formulas?

Comment: Sorry, not used to graph theory notation. I assume $G(n,k)$ is the set of graphs with n vertices and k edges that do not have any loops here, right? If that is the case, what exactly do you mean by $G(n,k)\leq G(n,k+1)$? Do you mean the cardinalities?

Comment: @AnCar yes edited

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding something. A graph with $n$ nodes that has at least $n$ edges will contain a loop since if we want to avoid loops, each edge must connect to a new vertex or must be disconnected from the rest of the graph (therefore adding $2$ new vertices). So let us pick $n=6$. Then the upper bound on $k$ is given by $k<\frac{1}{2}{6 \choose 2}$, so $k\leq 7$. There exists at least one graph in $G(6,5)$ (just the path going through the vertices), but no graph in $G(6,6)$.

Comment: @AnCar I think you misunderstand the word "loop". A loop is an edge from a vertex to itself; this is commonly not allowed in graphs, and it is not allowed here. You're talking about graphs without *cycles*.

Answer (score 1):

A sketch of an argument: For **labeled** graphs the result is trivial, because each graph corresponds to a choice of $k$ edges out of $\binom{n}{2}$possibilities. The unimodality of binomial coefficients then immediately gives the results. The only problem is that a graph may have a nontrivial automorphism group. However, the number of graphs with non-trivial automrphism group is very small as $n$ gets larger (for example, graphs with automorphism group of order two correspond to graphs on half the number of vertices, so is a super-exponentially-small fraction of the total. Yes, this part is sketchy.

Comment: It is a good point yeah but I am not sure if this asymptotic argument can be made rigorous. You are right that the property in question is related to $\binom{\binom{n}{2}}{k}$ and some sort of resulting binomial polynomial having unimodal coefficients.

Comment: I was thinking along these lines, but the number of graphs with non-trivial isomorphism group is only small when $k$ is large. For small $k$, you'd have to make a different argument. (Also, "graphs with automorphism group of order two correspond to graphs on half the number of vertices" is exaggerating the difference: the most likely way to get an automorphism group of order two is to have two vertices with the same neighborhood, so you only lose one vertex. This still makes a big difference to $\binom{\binom n2}k$, though.)